# Android: Adding admob ads to android apps

Tags: android, admob

Is it compulsory to add Adview lifecycle methods to the activity? What happens if it is not added? I have integrated ads in my app through XML but I have not added the Adview lifecycle methods which are specified in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration), but the ads are actually visible and working fine. Can anyone please explain the purpose of Adview lifecycle methods?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that it is required, but it would be a good idea to do it.  According to the javadoc for [AdView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.html), `pause` pauses associated extra processing associated and `resume` resumes it, so cycles won't be wasted on an add no one sees.  According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/SNUJFCxediU), `destroy` isn't needed any more, but is there for legacy reasons.